# Remove -cal target from Xcode

Tags: xcode, calabash, calabash-ios

Setting up an Xcode project for testing with Calabash. How can I remove the -cal target completely. There is already a -cal target in the repository that is quite old. I would like to set up fresh but it seems to create another -cal target when I run setup. Any thoughts? Xcode 6.

Comment: That's exactly what calabash setup does - it creates a new -cal target, plus some other stuff. You can remove old target manually, by opening the project and right clicking on the target and selecting "Delete". But after you run calabash setup, it will create -cal target again.

Comment: @almas after I run calabash-ios setup I get 2 -cal targets... why doesn't it get rid of one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The -cal schemes appear in 2 separate locations in Xcode.  The first location is to the right of the build button.  Click on the -cal scheme then go to Manage schemes and delete it from there.  To get the second location, click on the Show Project Navigator and then choose the name of the -cal scheme you used in the left pane (there should also be one called Pods that is automatically generated).  Then look under Targets in the Build Settings pane and you will be able to delete the second -cal scheme.